# City and Country from Microsoft Graph equals null

Tags: c#, azure

I am using microsoft graph to get user data from active directory. When I use sdk I got only basic informations about the users eg. "displayName",  "mail", "userPrincipalName", "id". Everything else have null value. My app in azure has permissions to see informations. When I turned on all permissions on azure the result was the same. How can I get city and country informations?

[image]

Comment: You should use the restful methods e.g.

https://graph.windows.net/someBussiness.onmicrosoft.com/users/6979110e-078e-400e-aaa6-429d680c53y0/city?api-version=1.6

Get a result
{"odata.metadata":"https://graph.windows.net/someBussiness.onmicrosoft.com/$metadata#Edm.String","value":"Keizer"}

Hover over the json as in these comments it does not format as I would expect it too.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-operations-overview

Comment: I am using this sdk :https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior since Microsoft Graph API endpoint returns a *default* set of properties for a `User` resource.

To return an additional properties, they need to be explicitly requested via the [`$select` query option](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#select).  In case of [msgraph-sdk-dotnet](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet) an additional properties could be specified like this:

```
var users = await graphClient.Users.Request().Select("companyName,city,country,contacts,contactFolders").GetAsync();
```

Another option would be to target [Microsoft Graph *beta* endpoint](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/beta-overview). In case of endpoint `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users`, along with default properties, at least `companyName`,`city`,`country` will be included in the result.

The below snippet shows how to initializes [msgraph-sdk-dotnet](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet) to target API `beta` version:

```
_graphClient = new GraphServiceClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta",
            new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) =>
                {
                    // Passing tenant ID to the sample auth provider to use as a cache key
                    string accessToken = await _authProvider.GetUserAccessTokenAsync(userId);

                    // Append the access token to the request
                    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
                }));
```